# Merge tag [atlassian-sourcetree] into [sourcetree]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

**EDIT:** Volunteer needed to create synonyms for [sourcetree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sourcetree) and [atlassian-sourcetree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atlassian-sourcetree), with [atlassian-sourcetree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atlassian-sourcetree) as the primary tag.

---

Both tags are referring to the same Mercurial and Git client. I think it should be merged into [sourcetree].

I know [atlassian-sourcetree] has been used more often, but I think people are more likely to search for "sourcetree" (the product) than "atlassian" (the company group). Also, auto-completion will respond to you typing "s..o..u...".

I do not currently have sufficient privileges (or know how) to do this myself.

Comment: Can't we just create a synonym? Why have you tagged this [burninate-request]? Which one needs to be "burninated" and why?

Comment: @Cody, you are right, a synonym will be better.

Comment: Almost a one year later and we can't still find somebody who can synonymize these two tages.

Comment: Oh well. Moving on.

Comment: Not sure who did it or when, but somebody has created the requested tag synonym.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [sourcetree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sourcetree) tag used to be full of questions about the directory layout of source repositories.  I did a retag some time ago to move the questions about SourceTree into the already-established [atlassian-sourcetree] tag, and effectively eliminated the ambiguous [sourcetree] tag.

Since it appears that all of the questions under the "new" [sourcetree] tag are actually about SourceTree, I think it make sense to synonymize these tags - but I think it is clearer for [atlassian-sourcetree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atlassian-sourcetree) to be the primary tag.

Comment: I wonder why anyone recreated it... I mean, enter [sourcetree] and (disregarding that tag) it will only suggest the atlassian variant...

Comment: Sounds good to me. Could you perhaps do it?

Comment: I will - I'm just waiting to see if there are any other thoughts about which tag should be the primary.

Comment: @PeetBrits Whoops - I don't have the required score to suggest the tag synonym.  We may need to find somebody else to suggest the synonym.

Comment: The synonym still hasn't been created 10 months later, I imagine it's hard to find someone with this privilege: "Creating a tag synonym requires 5 score in this tag.", this seems like quite an onerous requirement.  Maybe @larsks can do it for example: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sourcetree/topusers